# ${platforms.JDK_1.6.home}/bin/java": java.io.IOException: error=2

Tags: java, netbeans, jenkins

I have several projects on build and every one of the build even this one previously built,all of the sudden in a new commit I get this 
-init-debug-args:

```
BUILD FAILED
/jenkins/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/jobs/Virtualization_UI/workspace/nbproject/build-impl.xml:764: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "${platforms.JDK_1.6.home}/bin/java": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:494)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:612)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:476)
    ... 23 more
```

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE

I have rebuilt the project on `netbeans` and it works perfectly locally, I have the same config i had before on `netbeans` and on `jenkins` when it used to work but it just doesn't build thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did the new commit "all of a sudden" change this in `build-impl.xml`:

`${platforms.JDK_1.6.home}/bin/java`

That above is an unresolved variable. Without seeing the rest of your code/build, I can only guess: did someone change a hardcoded path to a variable (`${platforms.JDK_1.6.home}`)? You probably need to pass that variable to `ant` when you call the build.

That, or your build node (Jenkins master or slave) suddenly lost an existing environment variable called `${platforms.JDK_1.6.home}`